# Pyautogui/win32api scrolling does nothing when called per hotkey

Tags: python, winapi, pyautogui

The scroll function on pyautogui doesn't work on my system. I have python `3.8.10` installed and the latest version of `pyautogui`. The code I want to run is pretty simple:

```
import pyautogui
import keyboard

def scroll():
    scrollAmount = 100
    pyautogui.scroll(scrollAmount)
    print("Scrolling...")

keyboard.add_hotkey('shift+q', scroll)
keyboard.wait('esc')
```

I tryed to set the `scrollAmount` to a way higher number like `1000` or `-1000` without success. I tryed to scroll different apps like chrome or just an cmd terminal without success.

Is there something I am missing? Or should I use a different package to scroll?

Edit:

I also tryed to scroll with `win32api` but without success...:

```
import pyautogui
import keyboard
import win32api
from win32con import *

def scroll():
    win32api.mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL, 0, 0, -1000, 0)
    print("Scrolling...")

keyboard.add_hotkey('shift+q', scroll)
keyboard.wait('esc')
```

Comment: Can you edit your post to include a complete, working example (which doesn't contain syntax errors: missing parentheses)?

Comment: This is most likely caused by the fact that you're still pressing the shift key when the scroll wheel is fired. Consider adding a delay to give you time to release the shift key, or use code to automatically release the key immediately.

Comment: @Gaberocksall That did work! Adding a delay does work. I can also see that holding shift and trying to "real" scroll inside the browser does also nothing. Thanks

Comment: @Gaberocksall You did wrote "or use code to automatically release the key immediately.". How can I do that?